# Need help giving a recursive definition

Tags: algorithm, recursion, sequence

Given a sequence of unordered n integers, S = a1,a2,a3...

Give a formal and recursive definition of the length of the longest non-decreasing subsequence in term of n.

So, my thoughts are that if we're defining it recursively then each integer in the sequence is a sequence of length of 1 and contains a non decreasing sub-sequence of length 1. Would this be the correct way to say this or am I completely off?

Comment: By "longest non-decreasing subsequence", do you only consider subsequences of following integers ? Or are you allowed to reorder them as you want ? (I guess you're not, it would be too easy !)

Comment: @Theox only following integers, not allowed to reorder.

Comment: Doesn't this follow directly from the dynamic programming solution to the longest non-decreasing subsequence problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of this solution. I wrote it in pseudo-code.

```
define function non_decreasing_subsequence (index, sub_sequence, initial_sequence )
{
    sub_sequence.add(index)

    if initial_sequence[index+1] is not defined
        return lenght of sub_sequence

    if initial_sequence[index] <= initial_sequence[index+1]
        call non_decreasing_subsequence (index+1, sub_sequence, initial_sequence)
    else 
        return lenght of sub_sequence
}

for i between 1 and lenght of initial_sequence
    call non_decreasing_subsequence (i, empty_sequence, initial_sequence)
```

You'll calculate this way the lenght of every non-decreasing subsequence of following integers. Now you can get the max of these lenghts !

Comment: If downvoted, I'd like to have some explanations on what's so bad with my answer. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to have two variables in your recursion in addition to what element you are at. One with the historic max and one with the current length of ascending elements. If the array has element you are guaranteed 1 and count until the next element is decending, then you restart with perhaps a new historic max, or the list is at the end you return the max of current length and historic max.

Something like this Scheme implementation?

```
(define (longest-increasing-sequence lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (let recur ((lst lst) (cur 1) (hmax 0))
        (cond ((null? (cdr lst)) (max hmax cur))
              ((<= (car lst) (cadr lst)) (recur (cdr lst) (+ cur 1) hmax))
              (else (recur (cdr lst) 1 (max hmax cur)))))))
```

And here's a PHP version of the same using arrays instead of linked lists:

```
function longest_increasing_sequence($lst)
{
    $stop = count($lst)-1;
    if( $stop < 0 )
        return 0;

    // makes an anonymous function closed over &$lst, $stop and &$recur
    $recur = function( $idx, $cur_len, $max_len ) use (&$lst, $stop, &$recur)
             {
                 $new_idx=$idx+1;

                 if( $idx == $stop )
                     return max($cur_len, $max_len);
                 elseif( $lst[$idx] <= $lst[$new_idx] )
                     return $recur($new_idx, $cur_len + 1, $max_len);
                 else
                     return $recur($new_idx, 1, max($cur_len, $max_len));
             };

    // start recursion
    return $recur(0, 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Scheme is hopelessly too unreadable to anyone not familiar with it to be an answer to a non-Scheme question.

Comment: @Dukeling question isn't tagged with any language but I added an Algol dialect (PHP) as well for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Purely recursive:

```erlang
-module(lndss).

-export([get_len/1]).

get_len([]) -> 0;
get_len([H|T]) -> get_len(H, T, 1, 1).

get_len(_, [], C, M) -> max(C, M);
get_len(P, [H|T], C, M) when H < P -> get_len(H, T, 1, max(C, M));
get_len(_, [H|T], C, M) -> get_len(H, T, C+1, M).
```